paintComponent poor performance
When i fill a rect:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class App extends JPanel {

    private App() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new App();
            }
        });

    }
}


The performance of fillRect() is very fast, it takes 0 ms to execute.
However, when i have the exact same code but instead use drawString() like so:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class App extends JPanel {

    private App() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        g.drawString("hello", 100,100);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new App();
            }
        });

    }
}


The performance is horrible to say the least... it takes about 140-160 ms to execute. The paintComponent method also seems to be executed twice, first i get a print statement between: 140-160 ms and then i get the print statement: 0.
However, when i created a BufferImage, then used drawString() on the BufferImage  and after that invoked drawString() inside of the paintComponent() like so:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class App extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage buffer;

    private App() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        //BUFFER
        buffer = new BufferedImage(600,600,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
        g.drawString("test",100,100);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        g.drawString("hello", 300,300);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new App();
            }
        });

    }
}


Then drawString() inside the paintComponent has good performance, it takes 0 ms to execute ( even though i'm not using the buffer created at all in the paintComponent method). If i remove the code drawString() inside of the constructor, the code gets bad performance again.
What is going on ?

Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects only on the event dispatch thread.

When Swing calls drawString() the very first time it probably needs to load many classes and probably the font file too which takes time. Every subsequent call is much faster.

everything that i wrote above still is true when i did that :( i edited my question to let the EDT be the current running thread now!

You can't assess performance with such a simple test.  As was stated a lot is going on during startup.  Suggest you check out the tutorials.  Specifically, on how to paint

@ThomasKläger mmm... that makes sense  Can i speed up  that the process ?

also check this question: How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?

Essentially, same question asked here

Try changing your paintComponent to the following:  Note the difference in subsequent drawString calls from the first.  Threads can be tricky to assess. I would recommend you finish your overall application and then try to resolve any performance issues that may arise.  In that case it may be best to ask the question in code review
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int y = 50; y < 500; y+=50) {
           long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
           g.drawString("hello", 100,y);
           System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }
    }

On my Windows i7, the output is
25
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


( seems like something must be loaded/created/initialized the first time the drawString method is called: FontMetrics, Font (glyphs), ... )

Yes, you can simply put ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean().setVerbose(true); after the super.paintComponent(g); call and ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean().setVerbose(false); at the end of the method…
